# Can't hook my PC up to my computer screen using VGA

Tags: windows-7, vga, tv

I recently bought a Desktop PC, it was a rather old Dell, that I wanted to use with my TV screen. However after connecting my computer with my TV using VGA (Which is the highest available solution to this PC) it shows the computer starting up, but the moment it is done starting, it turns to the no connection screen. You hear the computer respond as it connects with the TV, yet it does not show me anything. I have tried every possible resolution that my computer had to offer, and I have changed the setting in the boot menu just to be sure. None of it worked. I have also tried updating the drivers, using the Intel program, that was also not the key. I hope someone here can help.

My PC is a Dell Optiplex GX620 with an Intel 82945G Express Chipset Family. My computer is running Windows 7.

My TV is a JVC.

Comment: Which model of TV do you have?

Comment: My guess is that after boot the PC uses a resolution not supported by your TV.

Comment: Did you try different refresh rates 30hz instead of 60hz or higher?

Answer (score 2):

What is probably happening is that your PC is starting the video drivers and switching to a resolution and/or frequency that isn't supported by your TV.

Your best course of action would be to hook up your PC to a regular monitor, start Windows (this will probably work, if not, there is a more structural problem) and update your video drivers to the latest version. Next, switch to a low resolution and frequency (800x600@60Hz will do) and shutdown. Connect to your TV and boot. If everything works, you can try how much you can increase the resolution. By default Windows will revert to the previous resolution in 15 sec's if you don't confirm, so that should go easy.